# Revision Number and build date in plugin and jars

Tags: java, eclipse, build, eclipse-plugin, bamboo

After build I see that some of the plugin contains the Revision Number and Build date in plugin or jar name and some do not. I want to know how it is configured? Is PDE build doing this its own or how?

Comment: How is the question related to bamboo? Do you let bamboo build your bundles? That would be a helpful information.

Comment: Yes I use Bamboo as build tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number in your MANIFEST.MF is like this:

```
Bundle-Version: 1.1.0.qualifier
```

PDE Build will replace the qualifier with build date time string. So maybe that some of your plugins's version number does't include the 'qualifier' tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I verified it!!

Comment: Could u please also let me know where in the PDE Build script the code/script is written for replacing .qualifier with revision no and date?